# Getting Bootstrap Popover content from Template

Tags: meteor

Bootstraps popover allows using the content property and setting a function. If I just pass the Template object it works well.

```
$('#popme').popover({content: Template.foo});
```

The problem with this approach is, that neither of my handler except the created is called. It would make my code quite maintainable if also rendered and events would be called.

Any trick?

Comment: Good question. I've never figured out how to get the popovers to work correctly with Meteor templates either.

Comment: I think it's a general rule for current Meteor templating system: if you manipulate DOM on your own something breaks: either Meteor reactive templates or your DOM manipulation. jQuery and plugins manipulate DOM explicitly.

Comment: Have you figured it out?